# HTML columns are not aligned properly?

Tags: html, css

if `print-bannertext-left` has no content then the `print-bannertext-center` shifts to the left. How can I fix this?

```css
.print-bannertext-left {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.print-bannertext-center {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.2%;
}
.print-bannertext-right {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like something you should be using a table for.

Comment: i can't use columns, there comes huge content inside that is printable, please help on it.

Comment: Some of your closing `</div>` tags are missing a `>`.

Comment: </div>  is a mistakenly there but it is nothing to do with that.

Comment: can some body help me in the existing code how i can fix it, without heading for any other approach, like table and any thing, i am in dire need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your columns a minimum height:

```css
.print-bannertext-left {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.print-bannertext-center {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.2%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.print-bannertext-right {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0.8%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-bannertext-left">

  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-center">
    8000-00-PO-201-01
  </div>
  <div class="print-bannertext-right">
    7/15/2015 4:41:11 PM
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use a table, it is more efficient
2. If you don't want to use a table, set a width/height to the print-bannertext-left in the case that there is no content in it, it will still hold some size therefore nothing will overlap it.

   ```
   <div class="col-1">
      <div class="inner-col-1">
         <p>column 1</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
      <div class="inner-col-2">
          <p>column 2</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="inner-col-3">
         <p>column 3</p>
      </div>
   </div>

   .col-1, .col-2, .col-3 { width: 30%; display: inline-block }
   .inner-col-1, .inner-col-2, .inner-col-3 { width: 100% }
   ```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb9tad3h/).

Comment: Try putting divs inside of the divs that are 30% width. Within those, you add your text or no text. And set those inner divs to 100% width so they will the parent div of 30% width.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me..would you please clear a little.